# Having trouble casting string to integer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert the string `"127.0"` to an integer.

I tried this function:

```
int getInt(string numStr)
{
 int result;
 int.TryParse(numStr, out result);
 return result;
}
```

But when I call it as `int x = getInt("127.0");` then `int.TryParse()` sets `result` to 0.

When I rewrite the function like this:

```
int getInt(string numStr)
{
 result=Convert.ToInt32(numStr);
 return result;
}
```

the same `getInt()` call throws this exception:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: because `127.0` is not integer. it has decimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that "127.0" is not an integer, it's a floating point number. You will need to parse it using one of the other floating point types (i.e. `double`, `float`, `Decimal`, etc.).

You may want to consider either stripping off any values after the decimal point and attempting to parse it, or parsing it as another type and casting it as an integer :

```
int result = (int)Convert.ToDouble("1.270");
```

You could also take advantage of the [`Math.Truncate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate(v=vs.110).aspx) function which would give you the integer portion of your value :

```
int result = (int)Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDouble("127.0"));
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `(int) Math.Floor( x )` produces different results than `(int) x` if `x` is negative.  For example, -1.5 would become 2 using floor but would become -1 when direct casting to `int`.  `Math.Truncate` will give the same behavior as the cast.

Comment: The more I was thinking about this, the more I thought that `Math.Round(x,0)` or `Math.Truncate()` might both be better options than `Math.Floor()`. I've updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to check the return value of `int.TryParse()`. If it returns `false`, then the string could not be converted.

Had you done that, you would see it returned false because *127.0* does not describe an integer value (it describes a floating point value).

Note that `decimal.TryParse()` would succeed here. You need to figure out if you need an integer or floating point value, and reject data that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

An int cannot contain a decimal point; that makes it either a double, a float, or a decimal. Try to pull the number minus anything from the decimal point over to the right, like this:

```
int getInt(string numStr)
{
  int result;
  string[] splitup; 
  string number;
  if (numstr.Contains('.'))
  {
    splitup = numstr.Split('.');
    number = splitup[0];
    int.TryParse(number, out result);
  }
  else
  {
    int.TryParse(numstr, out result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rion Williams is absolutely correct, IMHO.

Along with the fact that what you are parsing is not an integer, I'd personally use the TryParse method.  Many of the .NET types have it, and it's quite a bit "safer" (it won't throw exceptions) than just parsing a string.

Example:

```
string stringValue = "127.0";
int intValue;

if(Int32.TryParse(stringValue, out intValue))
{
    // return value
}

// handle the failure
```

If you don't like that, I'd wrap it in a try-catch...